# Creating a folder in google drive with node.js questions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-drive-api

I will preface this by saying I am very new to google cloud console and web development as a whole so I could be misunderstanding some very obvious things.

I am developing a web application with node.js as a project and want the user to be able to create a folder in their google drive. I have been using the guides provided in the Google Workspace (specifically this one: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/folder ) and I continue to run into different errors or problems that are likely due to my lack of knowledge on the topic. I am able to successfully authenticate and list files in the respective account's google drive, but I struggle to move on to creating a folder.

Here is my listFiles function that works successfully:

```
async function listFiles(authClient) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authClient});
  const res = await drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 100,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  });
  const files = res.data.files;
  if (files.length === 0) {
    console.log('No files found.');
    return;
  }

  console.log('Files:');
  files.map((file) => {
    console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
  });
}

authorize().then(listFiles).catch(console.error);
```

And here is my createFolder function that doesn't work:

```
async function createFolder() {

    const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
    const {google} = require('googleapis');

    const credentials = require('./credentials.json');
  
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      credentials,
      scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    });
    const service = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    const fileMetadata = {
      name: 'Invoices',
      mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    };
    try {
      const file = await service.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        fields: 'id',
      });
      console.log('Folder Id:', file.data.id);
      return file.data.id;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }

authorize().then(createFolder).catch(console.error);
```

credentials.json is the json file I got from the Oauth 2.0 in the google cloud console. Here is the error I get:
`Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field`

When I saw this, I decided to create a service account and try it that way because that has a 'client_email' field, even though I believed Oauth2.0 is what I want to use for the user to be able to perform these actions. When I created a service account and used the json file from the service account in the google cloud console, I don't get an error, and it seems to successfully create a folder, as it prints the folder id. However, it's not creating a folder it the google drive account that it authenticated previously. My guess is it creates a folder in the service account, which isn't what I want.

What am I missing or not understanding? I believe I'm likely missing something obvious but haven't been able to figure it out on my own. Thank you for reading and for the help.